# how to check lat long in circle or not sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have query that reply with this that latitude and longitude are in Rectangle or not.please check below code and image file.

My question is how to get result of circle? mylat long in circle or out
i have `"lat":"25.38227896335241","lon":"68.3395897859009"},"radius":"141.4213562373095"` in database

> example : "i have latitude  longitude of car i am checking latitude
>   ,longitude are in circle or not  if in circle result 'Car in Circle'
>   if not 'Car out of Circle area' this logic perfect in my rectangle but
>   i want circle result also"

```
DECLARE @g geography,
@pIn geography,
@pOut geography


DECLARE @minY varchar(10);
DECLARE @maxY varchar(10);
DECLARE @minX varchar(10);
DECLARE @maxX varchar(10);
DECLARE @carlat varchar(10);
DECLARE @carlong varchar(10);
DECLARE @CarIdx int;
select 
@minY = g.minlatitude , --N'29.7071393481341'
@maxY = g.minlongitude , --N'64.808349609375'
@minX = g.maxlatitude , --N'28.2463279710488'
@maxX = g.maxlongitude --N'63.292236328125'
from tblgeofencing as g where ShapeType = 'rectangle'
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + @minX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
@maxX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
@maxX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
@minX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
@minX + ' ' + @minY + '))', 4326);

select TOP 1 @CarIdx= idx, @carlat = f.lat, @carlong = f.long from checkgeofence as f order by idx desc
SET @pIn = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + @carlat +' ' + @carlong +' )',4326)
SET @pOut = geography::STPointFromText('POINT( 28.709860843942856 63.643798828125 )',4326)

SELECT Poly = @g, 
pIn = @pIn, 
pOut = @pOut
SELECT DistanceInMetersIn = @g.STDistance( @pIn ),
DistanceInMetersOut = @g.STDistance( @pOut ),
STIntersectsIn = @g.STIntersects( @pIn ),
STIntersectsOut = @g.STIntersects( @pOut )
SELECT STIntersectionIn = @g.STIntersection( @pIn ).ToString(),
STIntersectionOut = @g.STIntersection( @pOut ).ToString()
if( @g.STIntersects( @pIn ) >= 1)
update checkgeofence
set IsGeofence = 1
where idx = @CarIdx
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm65i.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure how the code shown relates to the question. It's not clear to me. Anyhow, asking if something is within a circle is equivalent to asking what the distance is between that point and the centre of the circle, and comparing that value to the radius. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: dear i have latitude  longitude i am checking latitude   longitude are in circle or not  if in circle result 'Car in Circle' if not 'Car out of Circle area'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get latitude and longitude of the car
2. get latitude and longitude of the place
3. get the desired radius of the circle
4. calculate the distance between the car and the place

**If you run this it should return a 1 which means the car is within the given radius of the place.**

```
declare @latitudeCar decimal(9,6) = 0.0275361;
declare @longitudeCar decimal(9,6) = 51.5064694;
declare @latitudePlace decimal(9,6) = -66.1711278;
declare @longitudePlace decimal(9,6) = -17.4125;


declare @source geography = 'POINT(' + cast(@latitudeCar as nvarchar) + ' ' + cast(@longitudeCar as nvarchar) + ')'
declare @target geography = 'POINT(' + cast(@latitudePlace as nvarchar) + ' ' + cast(@longitudePlace as nvarchar) + ')'
declare @radius float = 7000
declare @check float
declare @isPastCircle bit

set @check = (select @source.STDistance(@target)/1609.344)
--select @source.STDistance(@target)/1000

set @isPastCircle = (select case when @check < @radius then 1 else 0 end);
select @isPastCircle [isPastCircle], @check [carDistance], @radius [acceptableRadius]
```

standard U.S. miles check

```
set @check = select @source.STDistance(@target)/1609.344
```

km check

```
set @check = select @source.STDistance(@target)/1000
```

Comment: kindly check your query result always false

Comment: i want only to check latitude longitude in circle or not ,

Comment: Ok so same way really this is what it's doing.  Taking latitude/longitude of say the car, and if I'm in the "circle" or given radius then true else false.  Now what you may have to do is create a function to getRadius() from your circle in order to actually obtain said Radius, but then you'd run this once you have that value to determine if the point is in the "circle"